# Is the interaction $\gamma p \to \pi^+n$ allowed?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model

I'm doing an undergraduate lecture course in particle physics and I'm still getting to grips with the basics of interactions.

One of the example interactions I've been given in an exercise is $\gamma p \to \pi^+n$, and the question implies that this is allowed. However, I don't see how angular momentum is conserved. If I'm looking up the right numbers...

$$
J(\gamma)=1 \\
J(p)=J(n)=1/2 \\
J(\pi) = 0
$$

which means that I have $J=3/2$ on the LHS and $J=1/2$ on the RHS. From other similar (but not identical) questions, I have seen mention of the relative angular momentum *between* the two final-state particles, but I cannot find a good reference on how to deduce this...!

Comment: I don't know where you found your data, but the spin of a $\pi^+$ particle is actually $+1$, so the spin conservation holds in your interaction. For more information on the relative angular momentum, I recommend you the book Quarks and Gluons of Moo-Young Han (Chapters 1 and 2).

Comment: That may be its spin, but not its total angular momentum quantum number, J, which is 0 hence my confusion. See top of the summary table from PDG: http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/tables/rpp2018-tab-mesons-light.pdf

Comment: I checked the PDG, at the top you have the isospin $I=1$ for all pions.

Comment: Where did you find that $J=0$ for the pion?

Comment: In the link I just gave, it says J^P = 0^- at the top, simultaneously with the I^G = 1^-. I'm not worried about the isospin conservation, though.

Comment: You're right, I was on my phone so I missed it.

Comment: This is really curious. Assuming you got all your total angular momenta from the PDG, indeed this interaction seems to violate the total angular momentum conservation. While you can indeed have some coupling of momenta, this won't increase the total angular momenta (the relative angular momentum depends on the orientation of momenta, but it's just a difference, not an additional term). My guess is that either this interaction is ficticious and just part of a book, or the total angular momenta is equal to the spin (no orbital momenta) for this interaction.

Comment: Angular momentum adds according to QM rules. Are you aware of [J=3/2 resonances](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.108.433)?

Comment: First, study the *L*-wave decays of the [Δ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_baryon).

Comment: @Charlie  The pion  has spin zero.  see the table on the right. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion . its isotopi spin I is 1 because it is a triplet, pi+pi-pi0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with most of the discussion in @annav answer. But the key point is missing.

The J value that you quote are related to the *modulus* of the spin angular momentum of the particles ($J^2 = j(j+1) \hbar^2$). Therefore you can't add them without care.

The resulting angular momentum must not match the sum of its components but must fulfill the triangular inequality:
 If $J=S_1+S_2$ for vectors  one has 
$|S_1-S_2|\leq J \leq|S_1+S_2| $
for lengths

Hence the combination of a spin 1 and a spin 1/2 can give either 1/2 or 3/2. 
This fixed the paradox, whatever is the pion spin 0 or 1.

Comment: please note that *this specific* vector addition does not constrain higher angular momenta appearing in interactions, as in the one in the question,  it is  a lower bound  constraint .. .

Comment: I agree with last @annav comment. As implicitly  written in my answer, the baths hold when *orbital* angular momentum$L$ is not involved. In the more general situation, one would have to consider the coupling of three angular momentum, with relax the above inequalities if the orbital Austin number $\ell$ is not null. But most often one consider that $l=0$ (Born approximation)...

Answer (score 0):

In quantum mechanics there is angular momentum between two particles when they are bound it is called the L quantum number, and it corresponds to the macroscopic angular momentum concept.Angular momentum exists also between two scattering particles, the usual [classical rxp definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum).

Angular momentum conservation is a strict law both classcically and quantum mechanically.

In particle interactions we are in the quantum mechanical regime where operators will give us the state of angular momentum , and they impose a quantization on the angular momenta available for the interaction.

Because of conservation of angular momentum, researchers were forced to give an intrinsic angular momentum to elementary particles, called spin, so that the interactions will still conserve angular momentum. That is how we know the neutrino is spin1/2, for examle, so that the decay data of the muon do not violate angular momentum conservation.

In the specific reaction, the target proton has spin 1/2, and the incoming photon spin 1. Depending on the wavefunction  of the scattering, there is a probability that an l=1 could scatter, and then the conservation would give  5/2 on the left!. The scattered products can balance any incoming quantum numbers by going out with a *relative angular momentum* of the pion and neutron of 1 or 2 or .... It is all in the wavefunctions.

There is no problem. Conservation of angular momentum adds both intrinsic (spin) and relative angular momenta in the interactions by construction of spin. The spin definition is part of the successful fit to the data by the [standard model for particle physics .](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)